# Generic function declaration throws an error

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I need to declare a generic function which returns a generic cell, for this I implemented as follow,

```
private func getVisibleCellAs<Cell>() -> Cell? {
    if let visibleCell = self.registrationTableView.visibleCells.first, let expectedCell = visibleCell as? Cell {
        return expectedCell
    }
    return nil
}
```

now, I call this as

```
if let personalDetailsCell = self.getVisibleCellAs<PersonalDetailsTableViewCell>() {
            return personalDetailsCell.validatePersonalDetails()
}
```

But, it showing an error as (in function calling)

```
Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
```

if tried to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't explicitly specialize a generic function like that.

But you can do it like that:

```
if let personalDetailsCell: PersonalDetailsTableViewCell = self.getVisibleCellAs() {
    return personalDetailsCell.validatePersonalDetails()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Swift doesn't allow you to manually specify the generic arguments to pass to a functions, instead they must be computable from the context. You have at least three options here:

1. declare the variable type:

   ```
   if let personalDetailsCell: PersonalDetailsTableViewCell = self.getVisibleCellAs() { ... }
   ```
2. cast the result:

   ```
   if let personalDetailsCell = self.getVisibleCellAs() as PersonalDetailsTableViewCell { ... }
   ```
3. if the result is passed to another function, then the compiler should be able to infer that:

   ```
   func configure(personCell cell: PersonalDetailsTableViewCell) { ... }
   // later on
   configure(personCell: self.getVisibleCellAs())
   ```